# How to check if related table doesn't have record

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-query-builder

matches table has releationship with scores table.

I need to get all matches without record in scores table.

tryied smth, but didint worked:

```
$upcomingMatch = Match::join('scores', 'matches.id', '=', 'scores.match_id')
           ->where('away_team_id', '=', '1')
           ->orWhere('home_team_id', '=', '1')
           ->where('scores.match_id', null)
           ->latest('matches.match_date')
           ->first();
```

Comment: Do you have relationships setup between them? if so check into the `doesntHave` method

Comment: I strongly agree with @lagbox, If you have the relationships setup, then doesnHave is the standard and easy solution here. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use relationship, you can use `doesntHave()` , but if you use query builder as you write in your question, you may use these codes, I saw that your where condition need some adjustment to use nested condition. If you want to retrieve null record, then use `whereNull` in `scores` table which is not a relationship key with `matches` table, in this example I use `scores.id`

Get `matches` which its score is null (use `leftJoin` with some additional condition)

```
$upcomingMatch = Match::leftjoin('scores', 'matches.id', '=', 'scores.match_id')
           ->where(function ($where)
           {
               $where->where('matches.away_team_id', '=', '1')
               ->orWhere('matches.home_team_id', '=', '1');
           })
           ->whereNull('scores.id')
           ->latest('matches.match_date')
           ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$upcomingMatch = Match::join('scores', 'matches.id', '=', 'scores.match_id')
           ->where('away_team_id', '=', '1')
           ->orWhere('home_team_id', '=', '1')
           ->whereNull('scores.match_id')
           ->latest('matches.match_date')
           ->first();
```